# 12V DC to DC converter used in place of solar charge controller

Tags: battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, solar-charge-controller

I bought [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078Q1624B) product to use as solar charge controller.
My circuit consists of:
12V solar panel (5A?) -> 12V (DC->DC) voltage converter -> 12V 35Ah SLA battery 
The converter says its input is 20.9V from the panel, and its output is set to 13.7V, which is float voltage on the battery. That's all expected.
When I connect the converter output wires to the battery leads, the converter output voltage drops to 12.8V, and its input voltage 12.9V. This doesn't make sense to me.

The current on  the converter goes from 0.00 to 0.08 when I connect to the battery, and I can't adjust the current. I would expect the current into the converter to be around 5A or more since my panel is at least 5A.

Can someone with electronics knowledge explain why:

1. converter shows input voltage drops from 20.9V -> 12.9V when I connect its output wires to battery?
2. converter shows only goes from 0.00A to 0.08A when I connect its output wires to the battery?

Comment: The panel is only supplying 80mA (are you testing indoors?) which means very slow charging of the battery.

Comment: Its being tested outdoors, and the converter says 0.00A when only the the panel is connected, and 0.08A when the battery is then connected. I'd expect it to be higher.

Comment: charge the battery through a diode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plain DCDC converter is neither suitable as a load for solar panels, nor should you charge a battery with it (fire hazzard). To sink current from solar cells, you should use a MPPT capable converter and you need a charge controller to charge batteries safely. There exist devices which have both features combined.
A "solar charger" is much more than a buck converter.

Comment: Fundamentally it is just a buck converter **but** with different control logic, right?

Comment: As long as it has pots to control the output, I doubt this should be used to charge batteries.

Comment: well yeah, different control logic. not trying to output a fixed voltage

Comment: Hmm, I don't see this info in the desciption on amazon. You mean it requires a "different control logic" or do you think it's suitable for the OP's purpose?

Comment: I mean that I think a solar charger uses the same basic circuit as a buck converter to transfer energy, but the way the input and output voltage and current is controlled is different. Apologies for confusion

Comment: Man I hate electricity

Comment: Sim Son why exactly can't the converter be used to charge the battery? Isn't the only thing that matters the 13.7V & <= 3.5A input? Or is the battery flowing back into the converter or something and messing things up? I've seen the converters advertised as a DIY charge controller but not this model specifically. But then again I got this idea from a single post on 4chan.

Comment: Nevermind, this one specifically is advertised as "Can be used as a DIY solar charge controller" on the amazon page

Comment: @IHateElectronics I saw that marketing claim. But I think the term "DIY charge controller" means that it can be used to build your own charge controller, not that it is a charge controller itself. Which is ridiculous, because there are real MPPT charge controllers for the same money. It's a false - or at least misleading - claim in my opinion.

Comment: A charge controller has to live-measure the operating point of the battery and asjust chargin current respectively. Different battery types have different characteristic and a charge controller has to support the battery that is used. Charging batteries is quite complex and things can go wrong with potentially fatal consequences. The same applies for MPPT solar converters, though this is probably not that dangerous.